# Installable web app does not use icons while being installed on android

Tags: android, google-chrome, icons, webapp2

**I am deploying an installable web app with web manifest and icon images are not being used when installed on Android (I have not tried other platforms).**

I am following this guide:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en

**My system parameters:**

- index.html is available
- manifest.json is avaliable and is used when "add to homescreen" is being called
- App is properly installed (except for icons) - it points to the right URL and uses a standalone mode
- Images are available - one of them is used as browser icon and is visible in both desktop and mobile chrome browsers
- Mobile chrome version 51.0.2704.81
- Android version 6.0.1
- Azure web app is used to host the web app

**Manifest.json**

```
{
 "name": "Test app",
 "icons": [
  {
    "src": "icon-1x.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png",
  }, ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to configure an icon with resolution 256, probably due to the screen size of Nexus 6.